# How to sort List according to value in an array

Tags: c#

I have

```
List<string> strs;
double[] values;
```

where the `values` array contains the value of each of the string in `strs` list

```
Say strs={"abc","def","ghi"}
and values={3,1,2}
```

this means "abc" has value 3 and so on.

I wish to sort `strs` and `values` ordered by `values`, such that it becomes

```
strs={"def","ghi","abc"}
values={1,2,3}
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: It is better to use Dictionary for your case, instead of two lists

Comment: Why not use a Dictionary if you have such mappings?

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't mind storing both arrays in the same object, you could use a SortedList<int, string>

Comment: @george.zakaryan: This is less of a mapping and more of a list of pairs - I wouldn't class mappings as meaninfully sortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Array.Sort` method has an overload that takes two arrays and sorts both arrays according to the values in the first array, so make an array out of the list:

```
string[] strsArr = strs.ToArray();
```

Then sorting them can't be simpler:

```
Array.Sort(values, strsArr);
```

And then back to a list, if you need that:

```
strs = strsArr.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enumerable.Zip`, then sort the result, then extract the list of strings.

Something like:

```
var result = strs.Zip(values, (first, second) => new Tuple<string, double>(first, second))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Item2)
            .Select(x => x.Item1)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var sortedStrs = strs.Select((i, s) => new {Value = values[i], Str = s})
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
                     .Select(x => x.Str).ToList();
```

If you could logically put those values as properties of a class, such as:

```
class NameAndOrder
{
    public string Name;
    public int Order;
}
```

Then it would be better and more organized, and then you could do:

```
var items = new List<NameAndOrder>(strs.Count);

for (var i = 0; i < strs.Count; i++)
{
    items.Add(new NameAndOrder { Name = strs[i], Order = values[i] });
}

items.Sort((a, b) => a.Order.CompareTo(b.Order));
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you setting up these collections? Or are you given these two parameters?

You could create a `StringAndOrder` class and use **LINQ**:

```
public class StringAndOrder
{
    public string String { get; set; }
    public double Order { get; set; }
}

List<StringAndOrder> list; //create with this structure instead
var orderedStrings = list.OrderBy(item => item.Order).Select(item => item.String);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why Don't you use Dictionary Object..

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add("cat", 2);
dictionary.Add("dog", 1);
dictionary.Add("llama", 0);
dictionary.Add("iguana", -1);
// Acquire keys and sort them.
var list = dictionary.Keys.ToList();
list.Sort();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var strs = new[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
var values = new[] { 3, 1, 2 };

var newArr = strs.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
                 .OrderBy(x => values[x.i])
                 .Select(x => x.s)
                 .ToArray();
```